# Whether nuclear physics or nuclear engineering is suitable for doing research in nuclear fusion?

Tags: particle-physics, energy, nuclear-physics, fusion, nuclear-engineering

I want to do research in making nuclear fusion sustainable for electrical energy production , which field I should choose? and it is worth doing research in fusion now, since many of them are saying we are technologically more backward to make fusion for commercial energy production.
Additional details:Now I am in 3rd year electrical electronics engineering.

Comment: Can you email a company or other entity that would hire such a person, and ask them what they would want?

Comment: There exist centers where fusion is studied in tokamaks or inertial confinement fusion ( https://life.llnl.gov/ ). Fore example in llnl it seems they collaborate with universities and the experiments are done at the lab. https://lawrence-scholar-program.llnl.gov/selection.php .

Comment: Nuclear fusion can't be sustainable - it necessarily consumes a valuable element. And it's redundant now anyway for terrestrial uses. Anyway, fusion is just the sun in a box, and the difficulty is making the box: so, maybe materials science.

Answer (score 2):

This might not be on-topic for this site. Specific degree programs vary from school to school, so there's no way to know offhand. Certainly there may be overlap between "physics" at one school and "engineering" at another. At a larger school with both programs, the overlap may extend to shared faculty, or else the "engineering" program may be geared to recruiting staff for a particular reactor site. The only way to know is to ask.

If you're entering grad school, you need to interview with advisors to find one who shares your interests. Otherwise, you're in for years of misery. That overrides the name of the program completely.

Note that building a fusion reactor is a cross-discipline exercise. If for example you want to design magnets, an advanced electrical engineering degree would be appropriate — and you would want to belong to the research group that owns the superconducting equipment, regardless of whether it belongs to the nuclear department.

Comment: 1.i don't have any physics knowledge now, so how can i improve it so that it will be useful for my graduate admissions and research. It is worth doing research in fusion now, since many of them are saying we are technologically more backward to make fusion for commercial energy production.

Comment: @user1889670 An electrical/electronics engineering program with no physics? I hope you're only being modest. You should have at least taken calculus-based electromagnetism and circuit theory. Without some background the graduate programs will ask what happened. As for what to study, it depends what you want to do. I'd suggest to build on your strengths… don't be too modest :) .

Comment: I have studied engineering physics, calculus-based electromagnetism and circuit theory but i think this wont be sufficient for doing research in fusion so where can i start preparing for physics on a solid foundation like any online websites.

Comment: I'll just point you at [academia.se] and flag this question for migration there.

Comment: In academia also it is flagged like this one due to the reason that my question is opinion based.

Comment: @user1889670 Well, in any case the best course of action is to talk with the academic advisors at your school, and actual researchers whom you would like to help.